# JQuery adding a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want add a class when a `<li>` element clicked. but it didn't work. Here's JQuery snippet

```
$(".mama").click(function(){        
    var arr = ["cat","dog", "mice", "bird"];
    alink =  $(this).text();        

    $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        if(alink == value){
            $(this).addClass('hi'); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

And HTML

```
<ul id="animal">
    <li class="mama"><a href="#">cat</a></li>
    <li class="mama"><a href="#">dog</a></li>
    <li class="mama"><a href="#">Mice</a></li>
</ul>
```

i also have tried to do it by .map but nothing happen. please give solution and some explain. Thanks

Comment: Downvotes for everyone that encourages this poster to use implicitly declared and/or global variables and to define an array inside a function for no reason.

Comment: Rather than give suggestions on correcting this, we should be pointing out that using a click event to find the text of clicked element, and then looping over all possible text elements in order to confirm that it should be triggered is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @m59, I'm assuming this is a reduced test case, and the array serves a purpose in the real code. Good call about the global var though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".mama").click(function(){   
    var $this = $(this);     
    var arr = ["cat","dog", "mice", "bird"];
    alink =  $(this).text();        

    $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        if(alink == value){
            $this.addClass('hi'); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

because `this` inside the `each` is *not* the DOM element `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/reugB/1/

```
$('.mama').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean add the class `hi` to the clicked `li`, just do like below:

```
$(".mama").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".mama").removeClass('hi');
    $(this).addClass('hi')        
});
```

Comment: @Dogbert Yep, you are right. Removed that. But I don't think the op wants to add class to all the `li`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use **this** to refer to current element which was clicked.

```
$(".mama").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .hi { background-color: #f00 !important;}


 $('.mama').on('click', function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
$(this).addClass('hi');
```

});

Comment: make .hi class color important

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".mama").click(function(e){    
e.preventDefault();    
    var arr = ["cat","dog", "mice", "bird"];
    var alink =  $(this).find("a").text();        

    $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        if(alink == value){
            $(this).addClass('hi'); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

see reference [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)