# How to add class to a sub element with id in clicked div - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="hp"> add class here</span>
    <span id="hp"> Do not add class here</span>
</div>
$("#container").on("click", function() {
    code here
});
```

how do I click on the container then it adds a class="hero" to the first span with id in it? there are similar questions but not targeting the id. Thank you so much!

Comment: `id` should be unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery adding a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734307/jquery-adding-a-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it .Below have mentioned couple of options

```js
//Using find & eq
$("#container").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find('span').eq(0).addClass('myClass')
});

//Using first-child psuedo selector
$("#container").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find(':first-child').addClass('myClassRed')
});

//using children & first pusedo selector
$("#container").on("click", function() {
  $(this).children(":first").addClass('myClassBrown')
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: green;
}

.myClassRed {
  color: red;
}

.myClassBrown {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span> add class here</span>
  <span> Do not add class here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#container").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find('span:first').addClass('hero');
});
```

But yes, as pointed out in comments, IDs of the elements in an HTML page should be unique to avoid any unwanted bugs.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').click(function(event) {
        $(".container").parent().find('p').removeClass("color");
        $(event.target).addClass("color");
    });
});
```

```css
.color{
   color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <p id="hp1"> add class here</p>
   <p id="hp2"> Do not add class here</P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

id have to be unique so i changed first span id from **hp** to **hp1**

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="hp1"> add class here</span></br>
    <span id="hp"> Do not add class here</span>
</div>
 <script>
     $("#container").on("click", function() {
        $("#hp1").addClass("hero");
    });
</script>
```